# Postgresql - create materialized view

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW Available
REFRESH FORCE
START WITH CURRENT_DATE NEXT CURRENT_DATE + 1
AS
SELECT Table.item_id AS item_id, 
Table.reserv_id AS reserv_id  
FROM Table
LEFT OUTER JOIN Reserv ON Reserv.reserv_id = Table.reserv_id  
WHERE Reserv.start_date > CURRENT_DATE
OR Reserv.end_date < CURRENT_DATE 
OR Table.reserv_id IS NULL;
```

I want to create view which is update once a day but I get error: " syntax error at or near "REFRESH" ". What is wrong with it?

Comment: You syntax doesn't seem to be [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html). Where did you get the idea from?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use any REFRESH clause in PostgreSQL because it does not exist in PostgreSQL.

If the following query is correct in your database:

```
SELECT Table.item_id AS item_id, 
Table.reserv_id AS reserv_id  
FROM Table
LEFT OUTER JOIN Reserv ON Reserv.reserv_id = Table.reserv_id  
WHERE Reserv.start_date > CURRENT_DATE
OR Reserv.end_date < CURRENT_DATE 
OR Table.reserv_id IS NULL;
```

Following statement should work:

```
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW Available
    AS
    SELECT Table.item_id AS item_id, 
    Table.reserv_id AS reserv_id  
    FROM Table
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Reserv ON Reserv.reserv_id = Table.reserv_id  
    WHERE Reserv.start_date > CURRENT_DATE
    OR Reserv.end_date < CURRENT_DATE 
    OR Table.reserv_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Don't forget to refresh materialized views by event using trigger or by interval using crontab